# Implicitly insert unique records into foreign key table on insert

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mariadb, cascade

Is it possible to add into or remove `type_name` entries from the `type` table when a record is inserted in the `language` table?

I am receiving a #1452 (foreign key constraint) error:

> ```
> Cannot add or update a child row:
>  a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`language`,
>     CONSTRAINT `language_ibfk_1`
>         FOREIGN KEY (`type_name`)
>         REFERENCES `type` (`type_name`)
>         ON DELETE CASCADE
>         ON UPDATE CASCADE)
> ```

#### Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type` (
    `type_name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY(`type_name`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `language` (
    `language_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `language_name` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    `type_name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`language_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`type_name`)
        REFERENCES `type`(`type_name`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

#### Insert Statements

```
INSERT INTO `language`(`language_name`, `type_name`) VALUES
('C', 'programming'),
('Java', 'programming'),
('Python', 'scripting'),
('PHP', 'scripting'),
('HTML', 'markup'),
('XML', 'markup');
```

Implicitly inserted values due to `CASCADE`.

```
INSERT INTO `type`(`type_name`) VALUES
('programming'),
('scripting'),
('markup');
```

Comment: INSERT INTO `language`(`type_name`, `language_name`) VALUES
('C', 'programming')... 
I think you have wrong column order there, shouldn't it be (language_name, type_name) ?

Comment: It's typically a bad idea to do this. If the types are being added automatically then the `Type` table loses all meaning. It's not actually enforcing anything at that point. If you want to let the application (or users) just add whatever they want to the `Language` table then just make that a free-form field with no foreign key and no look-up table.

Comment: @piotrgajow: Thanks for that catch, I updated it.

Comment: @TomH: I want to restrict the values of the `type_name` in the `language` table so that they are unique.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl But they are not unique in the `language` table in your example. Each `type_name` appears twice. As has been said, if you are not actually restricting what can be inserted to the foreign key column, then your `type` table, and foreign key constraint is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have to use such a solution, you could use a trigger before insert on language table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON language FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    INSERT IGNORE INTO type
            (type_name)
        VALUES
            (NEW.type_name);

END
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this solution makes the table `type` utterly pointless, the only purpose it would ever serve is to get a distinct list of names without doing `SELECT DISTINCT type_name FROM Languages` - however, you could just create an index on on the `type_name` column making the query as good as querying the clustered index of a separate table, but without overhead of a trigger to manage the relationship. (N.B. this is not to say anything bad about the answer, it is a perfectly good solution to a problem that shouldn't exist)

Comment: @GarethD: Well, my table already exists as it does in the original question; except I have over 400+ rows of data which are foreign keys. :( But I did write a solution below to normalize the data appropriately, after the fact. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, using [piotrgajow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5271685/piotrgajow)'s response, I have come up with a way to normalize my table by adding a `type_index` to the `type` table.

I converted his trigger to a MariaDB/MySQL trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_language_type`
    BEFORE INSERT ON `language` 
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `type`
            (`type_name`)
        VALUES
            (NEW.`type_name`);
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I took this a step further and created a way to re-index the `type`s by creating a `type_id` column and associating it with the `language` table. And, in the process, dropping the `type_name` column from the `language` table.

```
/** Add the new type_id index to both tables. */
ALTER TABLE `type` ADD `type_id` INT FIRST;
ALTER TABLE `language` ADD `type_id` INT;

/** Index the type_id values.  */
SET @i = 0;
UPDATE `type` SET `type_id`=(@i:=@i+1);

/** Apply the new type_id values to the languages.  */
UPDATE `language` L, `type` T
SET L.`type_id` = T.`type_id`
WHERE L.`type_name` = T.`type_name`;

/** Remove all constraints and drop the type_name column. */
ALTER TABLE `type` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE `language` DROP FOREIGN KEY `language_ibfk_1`;
ALTER TABLE `language` DROP COLUMN `type_name`;

/** Set primary key for type and add constraint to the language. */
ALTER TABLE `type` MODIFY COLUMN `type_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE `language` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `type`(`type_id`);

/** Remove the trigger, because it is meaningless. */
DROP TRIGGER `insert_language_type`;
```

---

#### Before

```
+-------------------------------------------+   +-------------+
|                  language                 |   |    type     |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+   +-------------+
| language_id | language_name | type_name   |   | type_name   |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+   +-------------+
|           1 | C             | programming |   | markup      |
|           2 | Java          | programming |   | programming |
|           3 | Python        | scripting   |   | scripting   |
|           4 | PHP           | scripting   |   +-------------+
|           5 | HTML          | markup      |
|           6 | XML           | markup      |
+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

#### After

```
+---------------------------------------+   +-------------------- --+
|               language                |   |         type          |
+-------------+---------------+---------+   +---------+-------------+
| language_id | language_name | type_id |   | type_id | type_name   |
+-------------+---------------+---------+   +---------+-------------+
|           1 | C             |       2 |   |       1 | markup      |
|           2 | Java          |       2 |   |       2 | programming |
|           3 | Python        |       3 |   |       3 | scripting   |
|           4 | PHP           |       3 |   +---------+-------------+
|           5 | HTML          |       1 |
|           6 | XML           |       1 |
+-------------+---------------+---------+
```